# Name resolution (scoping) in an SQL expression

Tags: sql

I'd like to know if it's possible to reference a name defined in an outer scope. Although the below query works as expected, I cannot find any official documentation on how scoping works exactly.

Here is a sample query:

```
select Calendar.WorkerNumber
from Calendar, Activities
where Calendar.IdA = Activities.IdA and
      Activities.RequestedJob not in (
        select Jobs.Job
        from Jobs
        -- Here I am referencing Calendar.WorkerNumber which is defined in the outer scope
        where Jobs.WorkerNumber = Calendar.WorkerNumber
      )
```

Comment: 1) `A.RequestedJob not in (` alias **A** is not defined 2) Use `JOIN` sytnax 3) This is classic correlated subquery

Comment: @lad2025 You're right, I corrected the typo. How can I use `JOIN` if I'm using `NOT IN`? I could use a `JOIN` if I had a `=`.

Comment: ... from calendar JOIN activities ON Calendar.IdA = Activities.IdA where ...

Comment: @jarlh Ah right, you're referring to the previous lines, ok. But that's not really the problem and that syntax is allowed, isn't it?

Comment: @rubik It is obsolete

Comment: You can always refer to tables in "outer" levels, but not to tables in sub-queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JOIN` syntax:

```
select Calendar.WorkerNumber
from Calendar
join Activities
  on Calendar.IdA = Activities.IdA
where Activities.RequestedJob not in (
        select Jobs.Job
        from Jobs
        where Jobs.WorkerNumber = Calendar.WorkerNumber
      );
```

This is classic example of [`correlated subquery`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> In queries that include a correlated subquery (also known as a
>   repeating subquery), the subquery depends on the outer query for its
>   values. This means that the subquery is executed repeatedly, once for
>   each row that might be selected by the outer query.

From subquery you can refer to outer objects, but not vice-versa. If you use the same table twice (outerquery/subquery you need to use aliases).

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab t1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT t2.ID
                 FROM tab t2
                 WHERE t1.colx > t2.colx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I didn't know it was called like that. So this only works with the `JOIN` syntax and not with the older one?

Comment: Works with both explicit and implicit joins. (Doesn't matter.)